# How can I ensure that the Next.js router.query is not undefined?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm using `next.js` and the `import { useRouter } from 'next/router'`.

However on initial load, `router.query.id` is `undefined`. It quickly fills in, but that initial load is a killer.

I'm trying to figure out how to do it, and tried:

```
export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  // params contains the post `id`.
  // If the route is like /posts/1, then params.id is 1
  // const res = await fetch(`https://.../posts/${params.id}`)
  // const post = await res.json()
  console.log(params)
  // Pass post data to the page via props
  return { props: { params } }
}
```

but this returns an error:

```
Error: getStaticPaths is required for dynamic SSG pages and is missing for '/app/d/[id]'.
```

I can't use `getStaticPaths`, since `[id]` is variable and can be any number of things.

So what's the best way to handle this?

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't use `getStaticPaths`, since `[id]` is variable and can be any number of things."? If you mean that you don't know all the `id` ahead of time and you want the pages to be static, you can use [incremental static generation](https://nextjs.org/blog/next-9-4#incremental-static-regeneration-beta) by specifying `fallback: true` in the returned value of `getStaticPaths`.

Comment: For dynamic routes, if you want to use `getStaticProps` for data-fetching, you have to provide an array of paths using `getStaticPaths`  for pre-rendering the pages otherwise you will always get an error at **build time**.

Comment: I don't know all the `ids`. That's correct. I don't actually care about data-fetching during build time. I just want to ensure that the `router.query.id` is always there when the page loads.

Comment: Pages that are statically optimized will be hydrated without their route params provided, which means before the hydration query will be an empty object. [caveats section in dynamic routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes#caveats). That's the intended behaviour.

Comment: You can go for `getServerSideProps` with some sort of caching strategy with a custom server so pages will be generated on a per-request basis.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would do smt like this(without staticProps):

```
function Page(props) {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { query = {} } = router || {};
  const { id = 0 } = query || {};
  
  useEffect(()=> {
    if(id) {
      (async ()=> {
        const res = await fetch(`https://.../posts/${id}`)
        const post = await res.json();
      })();
    }
  }, [id]);

}
```

And this is what official doc. says:

```
// You also have to define a Post component in the same file (pages/posts/[id].js)
function Post({ post }) {
  const router = useRouter()

  // If the page is not yet generated, this will be displayed
  // initially until getStaticProps() finishes running
  if (router.isFallback) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>
  }

  return <h1>Posts are here</h1>;
}

// This also gets called at build time
export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  // params contains the post `id`.
  // If the route is like /posts/1, then params.id is 1
  const res = await fetch(`https://.../posts/${params.id}`)
  const post = await res.json()

  // Pass post data to the page via props
  return { props: { post } }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

After a bit research, have figure out this solution with `staticProps`:

```
export default function Post({ post }) {
  return <h1>Post is here</h1>;
}


export async function getStaticPaths() {
  return {
    paths: [
      { params: { id: '*' } }
    ],
    fallback: true
  };
}
    
export async function getStaticProps(context) {

  const res = await fetch(`https://api.icndb.com/jokes/random/${context.params.id}`);
  const post = await res.json()
  return { props: { post } }
}
```

Comment: @Shamoon Something is missing from the answer?

Comment: @VinceSanchezTañan for me it represents a dynamic `id`, what can be any value.